# Can't configure Dante

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, nat, dante

Config version: 1.4.x

I get "Connection refused" after default 30 seconds in curl and "Connection Failed" immediately in FoxyProxy.

Dante config:

```
logoutput: syslog stdout /var/log/lotsoflogs
logoutput: stderr

internal: 10.8.0.1 port = 32286
external: 10.8.0.1

clientmethod: none
method: none

user.privileged: proxy

user.notprivileged: nobody

#user.libwrap: nobody


client pass {
       from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
       log: error
       method: none
}



pass {
       from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
       command: bind connect udpassociate
       log: error
       method: none
}

pass {
       from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
       command: bindreply udpreply
       log: error
}
```

Network interfaces on the server:

```
enp0s2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr de:1a:24:12:d0:0f
          inet addr:10.16.14.29  Bcast:10.16.14.29  Mask:255.255.255.254
          inet6 addr: fe80::dc1a:24ff:fe12:d00f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:906951 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1238609 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1245533585 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:1052134029 (1.0 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:296 (296.0 B)  TX bytes:296 (296.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:438165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:677035 errors:0 dropped:17016 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:97069896 (97.0 MB)  TX bytes:840222645 (840.2 MB)
```

Working OpenVPN config for **example** of the network:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
internal: 0.0.0.0 port = 32286
```